# How would I replicate this input text effect where they're almost a merged box in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

Saw this image on dribbble. How would I create this effect in CSS? I'm referring to the two input fields being almost merged and having a not-full-width divider between them.

[image]

Comment: Wrap two inputs in div with white background. Then add bottom border to top input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#inputwrap {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #fff;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}
#inputwrap input {
    border: none;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    outline: none;
}
#inputwrap input:first-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tHfG/

Comment: I like the use of `<hr />`. Gives much more opportunity for customization such as a gradient line.